# install custom odbc driver on asp.net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, odbc, drivers

I have an issue whereby I would like a user who is accessing a web application hosted in Azure to directly request what ID's are currently available from a remote database and then make a request based on that info. Locally, how I do this is install an ODBC driver into our system then I can make calls to that driver using an ODBC connection within C#.

[image]

How would I do this in an ASP.Net web application located in Azure? This is really new territory for me so if you can reply with explicit instructions that would be greatly appreciated.

If I am not clear happy to elaborate...

Comment: Is your web app hosted on Azure Virtual Machine IIS or as a Azure App Service Web App?

Comment: Azure App Service Web App I believe.

Comment: Hi @Danrex, did you have any luck with this...?  I'm wondering if the same thing is possible in an Azure web app.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is similar to [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/installing-third-party-software-on-windows-azure-what-are-the-options/) 
You'd have to install the driver necessary before doing the call or during startup.